# In the definition of Carmichael number, why is it necessary to have $(b, n) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

In number theory, a Carmichael number is a composite number $n$ which satisfies the modular arithmetic congruence relation $$b^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$

for all integers $1<b<n$ which are relatively prime to $n$.

In the definition of Carmichael number, why is it necessary to have $(b,n) = 1$?

I need to understand this point, please.

Comment: Depends on the exact definition. If you are using $b^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, note this cannot hold if $\gcd(b,n)\gt 1$. To make it easier to answer fully, it would be useful if you indicated what exact definition you are referring to.

Comment: There's a lot of good literature on Carmichael numbers.  A quick online search turned up this: http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/carfind.pdf which looks like it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Any prime that divides both $b$ and $n$ will also divide $b^{n-1}$, making it impossible to have $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$.